# unable to display json data on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to build a highchart on my page. I do get the chart frame and title but now lines or legends. When I do:

```
document.write(output)

[ {"name":"dc1_sx02","data":[[1406269800,0.092],[1406271600,0.092],[1406273400,0.091],[1406275200,0.093],[1406277000,0.091],[1406278800,0.09],[1406280600,0.093],[1406282400,0.094],[1406284200,0.092],[1406286000,0.09],[1406287800,0.094]]},{"name":"dc1_sx03","data":[[1406340000,0.01],[1406341800,0.009],[1406343600,0.009],[1406345400,0.009],[1406347200,0.009],[1406349000,0.009],[1406350800,0.009],[1406352600,0.009],[1406356200,0.01],[1406358000,0.009],[1406359800,0.009],[1406361600,0.009],[1406365200,0.009],[1406367000,0.009],[1406368800,0.009],[1406370600,0.009],[1406374200,0.009],[1406376000,0.009],[1406377800,0.01],[1406379600,0.009],[1406383200,0.009],[1406385000,0.009],[1406386800,0.009],[1406388600,0.009],[1406392200,0.009],[1406394000,0.009],[1406475000,0.009],[1406476800,0.009],[1406478600,0.009],[1406480400,0.009],[1406482200,0.009],[1406484000,0.009],[1406485800,0.009],[1406487600,0.009],[1406489400,0.009],[1406491200,0.011],[1406493000,0.01],[1406494800,0.009],[1406496600,0.009],[1406498400,0.009],[1406500200,0.01],[1406502000,0.009],[1406503800,0.009],[1406505600,0.009],[1406507400,0.009],[1406509200,0.009],[1406511000,0.009],[1406512800,0.009],[1406514600,0.009],[1406516400,0.009],[1406518200,0.009],[1406520000,0.009],[1406521800,0.009],[1406523600,0.009],[1406525400,0.009],[1406527200,0.009],[1406529000,0.01],[1406530800,0.009],[1406532600,0.009],[1406534400,0.009],[1406536200,0.009],[1406538000,0.009],[1406539800,0.009],[1406541600,0.009],[1406543400,0.009],[1406547000,0.009],[1406548800,0.009],[1406550600,0.009],[1406552400,0.009],[1406554200,0.009],[1406556000,0.009],[1406557800,0.009],[1406559600,0.009],[1406561400,0.009],[1406563200,0.009],[1406565000,0.009],[1406566800,0.009],[1406568600,0.009],[1406570400,0.009],[1406572200,0.009],[1406574000,0.009],[1406575800,0.009],[1406577600,0.009],[1406579400,0.009],[1406581200,0.009],[1406583000,0.009],[1406584800,0.009],[1406586600,0.009],[1406588400,0.009],[1406590200,0.009],[1406592000,0.009],[1406593800,0.009],[1406595600,0.009],[1406597400,0.009],[1406599200,0.009],[1406601000,0.009],[1406602800,0.009],[1406604600,0.01],[1406606400,0.009],[1406608200,0.009],[1406610000,0.009],[1406611800,0.009],[1406613600,0.009],[1406615400,0.01],[1406617200,0.011],[1406619000,0.012],[1406620800,0.012],[1406622600,0.012],[1406624400,0.012],[1406626200,0.012],[1406628000,0.012],[1406629800,0.012],[1406631600,0.012],[1406633400,0.012],[1406635200,0.012],[1406637000,0.011],[1406638800,0.012],[1406640600,0.012],[1406642400,0.012],[1406644200,0.012],[1406646000,0.012],[1406647800,0.013],[1406649600,0.012],[1406651400,0.012],[1406653200,0.012],[1406655000,0.012]]} ]
```

I do get the nicely formated json output. Any ideas what I might be missing from this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>

    <!-- Include order: first jquery, then opencpu.js, and then your code -->
    <script src="opencpu/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="opencpu/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>
    <script src="opencpu/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="opencpu/export-csv.js"></script>

    <script>
    //init this script when the page has loaded
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
        //disable the button to prevent multiple clicks
        $("#submitbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var myname = $("#namefield").val();
        //perform the request
        var req = ocpu.rpc("output", {
          myname : myname

        }, function(output){
          document.write(output);
          //alert(output);
        $('#output').highcharts({
        //$("#output").highcharts('StockChart',{
        chart: {
            borderColor: '#98AFC7',
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 1,
                renderTo: 'output',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 10,
                zoomType: 'x',
                resetZoomButton: {
                position: {

                    x: -50,
                    y: -50
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 4,
                        lineColor: '#666666',
                        lineWidth: 5
                    }
                }
            },

            exporting: {
            enabled: true
        },
           legend: {
            enabled: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            shadow: true
        },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled:true               
            },

            scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                    },
            navigator : {
                enabled : true
            },
            xAxis: {
        type:'datetime',
                gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE',
                gridLineWidth: 1
            },
            yAxis: { // Primary yAxis
                labels: {

                    style: {
                        color: 'blue'
                    }
                },
                gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE',
                gridLineWidth: 1,

                title: {
                    text: '% CPU Utilization',
                    fontSize: '50px',
                    style: {
                        color: 'blue'
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            title: {
                text: '% CPU UTILIZATION',
                style: {
                    color: '#333000',
                    fontSize: '14px'
                }
            },


            tooltip: {
            positioner: function(){
                    return{x:20,y:-5};
                },
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}<b>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },

            series:output

    });
});

        //if R returns an error, alert the error message
        req.fail(function(){
          alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
        });

        //after request complete, re-enable the button 
        req.always(function(){
          $("#submitbutton").removeAttr("disabled")
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

    <style>
      #output{
        height: 600px;
        width: 1500px;
        border: 0px;
        padding: 3px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My First HighStock Chart!!!!</h1>

    <b>Your name: </b> <input type="text" id="namefield">

    <button id="submitbutton" type="button">Submit to server!</button>

    <div id="output"> </div>

    <br />


  </body>
</html>
```

I did a

```
document.write(output)
```

and copyied the output to the jsfiddle at this address:

http://jsfiddle.net/gsaray101/rmL1573f/

it works there so I am assuming the data is accurate, any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: Are you able to create a JSFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @Ondkloss, I cannot create a jsfiddle due to I have call an R function  which I am trying to create the chart output. It looks like I am getting the data back but there might be something wrong with data, that browser not displaying. For example, there might be [1] at the beggining of the data. How would I regex output to get rid of [1] in that data set in javascript.

Comment: @Ondkloss, when I do this to get rid of [1] from my data set,  var data = output.replace("[1]", ""); I get undefined is not a data type error, any ideas?

Comment: At the beginning, your timestamps should be multiplied by 1000. How we can reproduce your example, because as I see jsfiddle works.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, the backend that returns the value, does not have an outbound internet connection. So, I cannot create exact jsfiddle. As I've shown you, I am getting the data in the front end. Although the data seems to be json formated, it may be string or an array. How can we check the data type and maybe converted to json again in js. I am open to anything at this point.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I've did a alert(typeof output); it says it is an object. How do we convert this object to json data?

Comment: json is object, so its correct, so we need a live demo which will allow you to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by using JSON.parse() function in the ui as follows:

```
var data=output;
data=JSON.parse(data);
```